# Periodically exporting table info from mysql to phpmyadmin

Tags: phpmyadmin

So I've found plenty of answers to perform this kind of operation once-off, but not to do so periodically. I thought it would be interesting to share what might be the best technique to do this and gain some insight.

Picture we have a Windows database A. Database A keeps important information about the company, and is only available on the local intranet. However, we need to make some of this data available.

For this, we're looking to export this data to a MySQL PhpMyadmin database B.

The issue however, is that we want to do this automatically once per day, rather than an one-off export. How would one best go about achieving this?

Edit: To clarify, what I'm attempting to do is poll what might be the best way to go around any syntax issues that might arise, and what is generally "good form" to do in a situation like this, since to be completely honest this is the first time I really do something of the kind. Additional information to this specific situation you might find useful:

The MySQL database is hosted remotely on a web server, the Windows database is hosted locally.
PHPMyAdmin version: 3.5.8.2
Attached MySQL database: 5.5.42
Windows database: 2008 R2

The exact goal we're trying to achieve: We got a table "users" in the Windows database. Inside the table users we have a few values that we want to move to phpmyadmin. (firstname, name, birthdate...) Ideally I'm looking to use scheduled tasks to perform this once each day, so anything that could work with these (such as a powershell script) would be appreciated.

Comment: via a scheduled task on the intranet server.

Comment: What verstion of sql server, what version of mysql, are both servers in the same network... so many words, so little useful information...

Comment: I was proposing it more as a general question to see what my options exactly are, since I've read syntax issues arise between the two databases and what the most viable option would be to counter that programatically. I'll edit my question in light of that. (But yes, I was expecting to use scheduled tasks for this)

Comment: That's too broad for SO. If you have a specific question I'm sure you can find here more then one person that will by happy to help. as it stands now, the answer you will get (if any) is more a guess based on personal opinion then a profetional advice.

Comment: I'll edit the question even further to explain what the exact issue is.

Comment: Transfer data using JSON, encoding/decoding is available for almost every language you may use on localhost and remote server.